# How to change highlight color of filtered results in Dependency Hierarchy in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How to change highlight color of filtered results in Dependency Hierarchy in Eclipse? 
[image]

Comment: Did you find it ?

Comment: No, but I switched to python and emacs

Comment: Workaround is selecting the search results (click one, ctrl + a), which displays all items in the same style.